# Using functions in python to assign variables

Tags: python, function

```
def increment(n):
    """Return n+1
    increment(int) -> int
    """
    return n+1

def double(n):
    """Return 2*n
    double(int) -> int
    """
    return 2*n
```

How would I go about writing a single assignment statement that uses both of these functions to assigns 2*(n+1) to the variable m.

Comment: What have you tried? This is a fairly straightforward exercise and you won't learn anything if you're just handed the answer.

Comment: explain it better. Besides it looks trivial

Comment: `m = call_those_functions`. Hint: `2*n` -> `double(n)`, `n+1` -> `increment(n)`. Then just put them together in the right way.. I recommend playing around with (calling) these functions in IDLE (or similar REPL).

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: you have a point, but I disagree. Sometimes, the best way to learn is to see the code.

Comment: @SebasSBM: Please see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/08/04/9856634.aspx

Comment: @Andres: yes, it looks trivial for sure. The explanation have several possible interpretations, but, taking it literally, I think my answer is good - just my opinion.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: I get your point of view. I'm just showing one of the possible ways to assemble the code.

Answer (score 3):

We have two functions, let's look at what they do:

```
double(n) -> 2 * n
increment(n) -> n + 1
```

So, in the [REPL or "Interactive Mode"](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interpreter.html) (or in [IDLE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html)):

```
n = 2
double(n)
> 4
increment(n)
> 3
n
> 2              # note that n was not reassigned
```

Now, looking at the equation `m = 2*(n+1)`, we can see that it can be rewritten like so:

```
let n1 = n + 1
     m = 2 * n1
```

And applying the definitions from above:

```
n1 = increment(n)
m = double(n1)
# and, by substitution of n1
m = double(increment(n))
```

Trying it out interactively:

```
n = 4
m = double(increment(n))
> 10
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
def combo(n):
    return double(increment(n))
```